# How do I extract the value from this collection to be inserted into a many to many table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, collections

How do I extract this collection ?

/*Collection */

```
Collection {#366
  #items: array:1 [
    "books" => array:2 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "id" => 4
        "description" => "Adipisci non enim vi"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "id" => 6
        "description" => "Ex et alias et cum b"
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

to be inserted into a table called book_publisher which contains `book_id` `publisher_id` which is equal to the current publisher_id and also description equals to the `book_details`..

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use collection method [pluck-method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck) to put the `book_id` as key, and the `description` as value,
   and then use [mapWithKeys](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-mapwithkeys) to change the `description` to `['book_details' => $item]`.
2. Use many-to-many [attach-method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) to build the relationship.

Assuming the collection is stored in `$items`:

```php
$datas = $items->pluck('description', 'id')->mapWithKeys(function($item, $key) {
    return [$key => ['book_details' => $item]];
});

$current_publisher->books()->attach($datas);
```